# Best Design for a User/Role Management System?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Here's a software design question I've encountered several times and have never found an ideal solution for (I'm also dealing with it now again.)

Many applications need some form of user/role management.  You have base users, groups that these users can belong to (not limited to just one), roles and permissions they have, organizational units, and a whole bunch of properties and other features that are project-specific.

My question is, what ways do people know of and/or have experience with to design and build a really dynamic, flexible user management system?  Are there any design patterns you know of that really help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because every organization has different needs, you should adapt your design while designing and building a dynamic and flexible user management system.

Role Based Access Control (RBAC) is a common approach. In this model, users are assigned roles, and the roles have corresponding permissions. As a result, instead of granting permissions directly to users, permissions are granted to roles. Users who are allocated to a role inherit the permissions associated with that role.

Role hierarchies can be used to improve efficiency and scalability. Higher-level roles in a role hierarchy inherit permissions from lower-level ones. As a result, when a modification is made to a higher-level position, it is propagated to all lower-level roles.

[image: This is an example of Role-based access control]

[Role-based access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)

[Designing permissions for a SaaS app](https://uxdesign.cc/design-permissions-for-a-saas-app-db6c1825f20e)

[Demystifying Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) Pattern: A Comprehensive Guide](https://medium.com/@solidity101/%EF%B8%8F-demystifying-role-based-access-control-rbac-pattern-a-comprehensive-guide-bd18b144fc81)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it will help you, but if you have the opportunity you should check out the built in functionality in ASP.NET . You could get some pointers, at least, from there.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 2 of [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237): A Library of Universal Data Models for All Enterprises might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Scott Mitchell's ASP.NET 2.0 Membership, Roles and Profile Tutorial series:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx